# Current user flag summary link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks, flag-history

Currently we can link to the current user's page (i.e. when a user clicks the link it'll link to their own page) by using `http://SE-site.com/users/current` which is great!

We can also link to specific tabs by using `.../current?tab=reputation` - also great.

However, it'd be lovely if we could link to the flag summary page in this way. That would mean something like `.../users/current/flag-summary` or `.../users/flag-summary/current` would link to the user's flag summary page.

Can we get this feature implemented?

---

**Edit**

As [ShadowWizard commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248109/current-user-flag-summary-link#comment812784_248109), the proper name is apparently "flag history", but the current URL is `.../flag-summary/`. If we want to change the URL to match the proper name, we should change both to `flag-history` at the same time.

Comment: That's actually called "flag history", but I won't be too picky. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was basing the name off of the URL for it... maybe that should be changed?

Comment: You know what... that sounds like a good idea! Two feature requests in one. :D

Comment: It probably does not work for other links ending with user id either. Such as `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/xxxxxxx` or `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/xxxxxxx`.

Comment: There's actually a few places where `/current` doesn't work. (*See [Inconsistent support for /current](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298748/351462)*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this feature has been implemented. Now we can navigate to our flag summary via `.../users/flag-summary/current`

Please find the reference in the help center - [What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/declined-flags)

> Often moderators will provide a specific reason for declining a flag. You can view these by visiting [your flagging history](/users/flag-summary/current).